# What should I do when the review process takes longer than expected?

Tags: peer-review, journals, editors

First case: my paper got minor revisions and is "under review" since 27/10. Is it normal to take all this time for minor revisions? Can I ask the editor to remind the reviewers or can I ask for their deadline?

Second Case: other paper sent to an issue with these details:

> Final manuscript due: 14 November, 2022
> Tentative publication date: 14 February, 2023

but it is under review since 23/9. I sent a message to the editor of the issue with no response, so I sent another one to the editor of the journal and received this reply:

> The journal aims to complete the peer-review process in the shortest time possible without sacrificing quality and integrity. However, a number of factors influence the actual time it takes to complete the process, most notably the availability and responsiveness of qualified and able reviewer.

What should I do with this paper? Can I ask the editor of the journal to contact the editor of the issue to inquire about the problem or if the dates of their issue changed?

Comment: (1) Please ask a question in your title and (2) please don't use code formatting for things that aren't code.

Comment: I tried to edit the post and hope can get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to do, actually. Writing again will have little effect other than to increase the workload of the editor, reviewers (perhaps), and staff. The response you got says it clearly. The system doesn't work on strict deadlines, and can't since humans are involved.

You won't change any decisions or affect any deadlines or scheduling by writing. It is just noise that might require someone to compose a reply like the one you've already gotten. Patience is warranted.

If you require information for some other purpose, you can ask for that, saying why, but if it is just worry and/or curiosity, then I recommend that you let it go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer . excuse me , what if the status change to under review again with different date ? does that mean the other reviewer didn't review it and the editor assign new reviewers ? and if so , will the duration for the reviewing process be another months :-( or just will review the comments

Comment: It can mean a lot of things, including disagreements among reviewers, non responsive reviewers, etc. The time can't really be well estimated. They strive for efficiency but it is an elusive target. Too many moving parts, not well connected.

Comment: @user1 you seem to be checking the status a lot. That is not healthy. You have submitted your papers, so you have done all you could. Now it is out of your hands. There is no action you can take that will influence what happens. Any micro-second you spend on these papers is wasted time. So don't check on it. Forget these papers existed. Instead spent that time on things you can change: your next paper, doing nice things for your neighbors, co-workers, who-ever, or just relax. All of that is more productive than looking at the status, which is random noise most of the time anyhow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice but those paper for my phd-defense that has a deadline so i'm feeling confused and stress . i hope i can get an accept nearly

Comment: FWIW, accepted (in press) papers are almost as good as published ones; PhD students starting too late with their publications is a very common thing.